# public override ICollection AssociatedComponents doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, document, visual-studio-2017, outline

I want override AssociatedComponents for MyControlDesigner for MyComponent.

But when I add any component into Collection 
the Document Outline Window in Visual Studio became Empty.

```
//Ok
    public override ICollection AssociatedComponents
    {
      get
      {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        //items.Add(Grid.HorzScrollBar);
        return (ICollection)items;
      }
    }
```

[image]

```
//Not Ok
    public override ICollection AssociatedComponents
    {
      get
      {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        items.Add(Grid.HorzScrollBar); //Add any component
        return (ICollection)items;
      }
    }
```

// Now Document Outline Window is always empty.

[image]

I tried to Debug Visual Studio to understand how Document Outline work, but looks like Microsoft does not allow you to view the source code of this part of .Net.[image]

Does anyone know for what reasons Document Outline Window does not display data?

Comment: 1) What do you want to do?  2) Is the `Grid.HorzScrollBar` a nested component of the control which for you are creating the designer?

Comment: 1) I want to Tree for Grid component. Grid is complex component and have many properties, some of them is complex (class type) properties with subproperties. I want to add some class type to the Grid as branches of Document Outline.

Comment: 2) Grid.HorzScrollBar is a class type property. It is not a nested component. Why it should be nested a component. 
AssociatedComponents  allows to return collection of any objects.
So developer can decide what object should be considered as AssociatedComponents  for component.